# Facebook signed request problem

Tags: facebook, github, json

I want to write a fangate for my facebook page, but it didnt work and i doesnt find any help on the inter net

```
require 'facebook.php';

$app_id = '16850872653xxxx';
$app_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => $app_id,
'secret' => $app_secret,
'cookie' => true
));

$signed_request = $_REQUEST['signed_request'];

//echo $signed_request;

list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 


// decode the data
$sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
$data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

// check sig
$expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $app_secret, $raw = true);

function base64_url_decode($input) {
return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}

if($signed_request->page->liked) {
echo "This content is for Fans only!";
} else {
echo "Please click on the Like button to view this tab!";
}
```

I am using this code... but it just jumps to github where i have downloaded the facebook.php....

does anybody see a problem with this code?

the require just jumps to github and the json_decode doesnt work...

Comment: FYI, even though you have edited this post, your app id and app secret are still visible (in the revision history); you may want to regenerate your app secret (in the FB developers area) to keep your app secure.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few errors with the code you sent. This is what I use, and it works:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['signed_request'])) {
      $encoded_sig = null;
      $payload = null;
      list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $_REQUEST['signed_request'], 2);
      $sig = base64_decode(strtr($encoded_sig, '-_', '+/'));
      $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/'), true));
      if($data->page->liked) {
          echo "This content is for Fans only!";
        } else {
          echo "Please click on the Like button to view this tab!";
        }
    }
```

And don't post your application secret key on the forum, please edit your post as soon as possible.

Comment: thanks... do I have to use a server that supports https? sorry I cant change my post... or I even dont know how to... but i have deleted the app...

Comment: Well, you don't have to use a SSL certificate, but facebook will show a warning to everyone using the new secure page every time they visit your app. Such users are rare now, just a few percent, but they are very loud and soon you will start getting mails like "Why isn't your app secure". I recommend you get SSL soon.

Comment: Great block of code that, just what I was after - Thanks @DannyKK

Comment: Excellent code. May I just add that as of today all canvas apps must have an SSL certificate (HTTPS)