# facebook signed request without authenticating app?

Tags: facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook signed request problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703585/facebook-signed-request-problem)

Can i get signed request data in my fanpage tab without authenticating user? I want to get if user has liked my page or not.

I get data when i authenticate user through my application. Dont know why it is empty without authentication. I just need to check if user has liked my page or not.

Comment: Besides, what stopped you from just checking it for yourself, if there _is_ a signed_request parameter in that case …?

Comment: not duplicated. That was old api. I am using latest one.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pagetab/ the second example shows the flow if the user hasn't authed your app

Comment: the API you're using is irrelevant, it's still the `signed_request`- the method to extract information from it in the PHP SDK is getSignedRequest

Answer (score 0):

I shifted my code to another server and everything was worked fine. I don't know what was the problem with my server. Please drop your answer if you find any reason.